# Equivalence relation proof with given specific condition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations prove:

$R\cup S$ is equivalence relation iff $R\cup S=S \circ R$

So far I proved simmetry and reflexivity, but I'm stuck with transitivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reflexivity, we always have $R\cup S\subseteq S\circ R$ and $R\cup S\subseteq R\circ S$.

Now, if $R\cup S=S\circ R$, then by the above we have $S\circ R\subseteq R\circ S$. Then, using symmetry and taking converse, we get $R\circ S\subseteq S\circ R$. So, that,
$$S\circ R\circ S\circ R\ = \ S\circ S\circ R\circ R\ \subseteq\ S\circ R\,,
 $$
hence it is transitive.

For the other direction, if $R\cup S$ is equivalence relation, as it contains both $R$ and $S$, and as it is transitive, we have $R\circ S\subseteq R\cup S$ and $S\circ R\subseteq R\cup S$. Together with the above inclusions it means that, in this case we actually have
$$R\circ S\ =\ R\cup S\ =\ S\circ R\,.$$

Comment: Thank you, I forget to write that in begining. =)

Comment: Wait.. I used $R\circ S\subseteq S\circ R$ in the main line...

Comment: Ok, since both $R$ and $S$ are symmetric, this doesn't mean a problem here, I corrected.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it like this:
$(S\circ R)^{-1} = R^{-1} \circ S^{-1}=R \circ S$
And because of symmetry od $R \cup S$:  

$R \circ S=(S\circ R)^{-1}=(R \cup S)^{-1}=R \cup S=S\circ R$